# solaris + manipulate lltconfig command

Tags: solaris, shell-scripting, solaris-10

I work on Solaris 10 machines (eg `de1a` and `du1b`). Regarding the `lltconfig` command, is it possible to view only one device (eg NIC `e1000g0`) and not the entire list?

For example I want to get only status about `e1000g0`, something like the following:

```
 lltconfig .....
      Link 0 (e1000g0):
      Node   0 du1a      :   00:21:28:14:76:68
      Node   1 du1b      :   00:21:28:59:72:C4  permanent
```

Another option is to manipulate `lltconfig -a list` in order to get what I want (by `awk` or `sed` or `ksh` etc).

Here's an example of what I get from `lltconfig -a list` (in this case I get the entire list but I need only status for `e1000g0`):

```
 lltconfig -a list
      Link 0 (e1000g0):
      Node   0 du1a      :   00:21:28:14:76:68
      Node   1 du1b      :   00:21:28:59:72:C4  permanent

      Link 1 (e1000g1):
      Node   0 du1a      :   00:21:28:14:76:69
      Node   1 du1b      :   00:21:28:59:72:C5  permanent

      Link 2 (e1000g2):
      Node   0 du1a      :   00:21:28:14:76:99
      Node   1 du1b      :   00:21:28:59:72:95  permanent
```

Comment: what is the `lltconfig` command ?  never heard of it on Solaris.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the `lltconfig` command on my Solaris 10 box, so I can't check the manpage; it's possible that there's already an option you could pass that would limit the display to just one interface.

In any case, this is something that `sed` could do for you, eg:

```
lltconfig -a list | sed '/e1000g0/,/^$/!d;/^$/d'
```

You could then add a shell function so you don't have to type that every time, eg:

```
function lltstatus() { lltconfig -a list | sed "/$1/,/^$/\!d;/^$/d" }
```